# Как десериализовать чужой xml в собственный класс?

Tags: c#, xml

Есть вот такой xml, например:

```
<eveapi version="2">
<currentTime>2015-11-19 05:21:29</currentTime>
<result>
<serverOpen>True</serverOpen>
<onlinePlayers>14528</onlinePlayers>
</result>
<cachedUntil>2015-11-19 05:23:43</cachedUntil>
</eveapi>
```

И сделаем простой класс:

```
public class ServerStatus
{
    public bool Online { get; set; }
    public int Players { get; set; }
}
```

Как десериализовать данный xml в этот класс, без ручного парсинга, полагаю, с использованием аттрибутов?

UPD: Если навешать аттрибуты и попробовать через `XmlSerializer`, то он может вернуть класс только если все поля будут строковыми, как это можно обойти?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно воспользоваться утилитой [xsd.exe](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/x6c1kb0s%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) для генерации набора классов. Или ещё проще: скопировать xml в буфер обмена и в Visual Studio воспользоваться командой меню

> Edit > Paste Special > Paste XML As Classes.

Правда, при этом генерируется слишком многословный код с обилием атрибутов, многие из которых в большинстве случаев можно убрать.

Вот вручную созданные классы, с именами свойств в PascalCase, как того требуют гайдлайны:

```
[XmlRoot("eveapi")]
public partial class EveApi
{
    [XmlElement("currentTime")]
    public string CurrentTime { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("result")]
    public ServerStatus Status { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("cachedUntil")]
    public string CachedUntil { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("version")]
    public byte Version { get; set; }
}

[XmlType("eveapiResult")]
public class ServerStatus
{
    [XmlElement("serverOpen")]
    public bool Online { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("onlinePlayers")]
    public int Players { get; set; }
}
```

Я слишком долго реагировал, и **PashaPash** уже написал, что True в xml не распознаётся сериализатором как булево значение.
Приведу ещё один способ решения этой проблемы.
Создадим свой класс xml-ридера:

```
class MyXmlReader : XmlTextReader
{
    public MyXmlReader(Stream input) : base(input) { }

    public override string ReadString()
    {
        string value = base.ReadString();

        if (Name == "serverOpen")
            return value.ToLower();
        else
            return value;
    }
}
```

И используем его при чтении ответа от сервера:

```
EveApi eveApi;
var xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(EveApi));

using (var reader = new MyXmlReader(responseStream))
{
    eveApi = (EveApi)xs.Deserialize(reader);
}

Console.WriteLine(eveApi.CurrentTime);
Console.WriteLine(eveApi.CachedUntil);
Console.WriteLine(eveApi.Version);

ServerStatus serverStatus = eveApi.Status;
Console.WriteLine(serverStatus.Online);
Console.WriteLine(serverStatus.Players);
```

---

Гулять, так гулять.
Кроме уже описанных двух есть и другие способы нужного чтения не совсем корректных данных:

- реализация интерфейса `IXmlSerializable`. Достоинство - абсолютная гибкость. Недостаток - полностью ручное написание кода разбора.
- подписка на событие `XmlSerializer.UnknownElement`.

  ```
  var xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(EveApi));
  xs.UnknownElement += UnknownElement;
  eveApi = (EveApi)xs.Deserialize(responseStream);
  ```

  ```
  void UnknownElement(object sender, XmlElementEventArgs e)
  {
      if (e.Element.Name == "serverOpen")
      {
          var serverStatus = (ServerStatus)e.ObjectBeingDeserialized;
          serverStatus.Online = bool.Parse(e.Element.InnerText);
      }
  }
  ```

Чтобы это событие сработало, удаляем в классе ServerStatus атрибут у свойства Online:

```
//[XmlElement("serverOpen")]
public bool Online { get; set; }
```

Теперь сериализатор, встретив xml-элемент serverOpen не будет знать, к чему его привязать и будет вызвано это событие. В нём мы вручную парсим значение и записываем его в нужное свойство.

Comment: Спасибо за комментарий, интересный способ, буду думать как лучше поступить)

Comment: @anweledig - Добавил пример с подпиской на событие, зацените. ЗЫ: можно было бы ограничиться плюсиком мне, а ответ оставить PashaPash'е.

Comment: Нет, нет, Ваш вариант с переопределением ридера именно то что нужно) Очень малой кровью все обходится и не нужно больше никаких костылей в самой модели данных)

Answer (score 3):

`XmlSerializer` не распарсит `True`/`False` как `bool`. Возможные обходные пути - создать строковое свойство в том же классе:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ServerStatusResponse));

        using (var stream = File.OpenRead(@"c:\temp\1.xml"))
        {
            var status = (ServerStatusResponse)serializer.Deserialize(stream);
        }

    }
}

[XmlRoot("eveapi")]

public class ServerStatusResponse
{
    [XmlElement("result")]
    public ServerStatus Result { get; set; }
}

public class ServerStatus
{
    [XmlElement("serverOpen")]
    public string OnlineString
    {
        get
        {
            return this.Online.ToString();
        }
        set
        {
            this.Online = Boolean.Parse(value);
        }
    }

    [XmlIgnore]
    public bool Online { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("onlinePlayers")]
    public int Players { get; set; }
}
```

... или в классе-наследнике, если не хочется чтобы оно в коде шумело:

```
[XmlRoot("eveapi")]

public class ServerStatusResponse
{
    [XmlElement("result", Type=typeof(ServerStatusAdapter))]
    public ServerStatus Result { get; set; }
}

public class ServerStatus
{
    [XmlIgnore]
    public bool Online { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("onlinePlayers")]
    public int Players { get; set; }
}

public class ServerStatusAdapter : ServerStatus
{
    [XmlElement("serverOpen")]
    public string OnlineString
    {
        get
        {
            return this.Online.ToString();
        }
        set
        {
            this.Online = Boolean.Parse(value);
        }
    }
}

[XmlRoot("eveapi")]

public class ServerStatusResponse
{
    [XmlElement("result", Type=typeof(ServerStatusAdapter))]
    public ServerStatus Result { get; set; }
}

public class ServerStatus
{
    [XmlIgnore]
    public bool Online { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("onlinePlayers")]
    public int Players { get; set; }
}

public class ServerStatusAdapter : ServerStatus
{
    [XmlElement("serverOpen")]
    public string OnlineString
    {
        get
        {
            return this.Online.ToString();
        }
        set
        {
            this.Online = Boolean.Parse(value);
        }
    }
}
```

но ради двух полей - это как стрельба из пушки по воробьям. гораздо проще взять L2XML и обойтись без шаманства:

```
var doc = XDocument.Load(@"c:\temp\1.xml");
var status = doc.Descendants("result")
    .Select(r => new ServerStatus
    {
        Online = (bool)r.Element("serverOpen"),
        Players = (int)r.Element("onlinePlayers")
    })
    .Single();
```

---

Eсть еще вариант - через xslt, или просто заменой текста, привести к true/false до десериализации. Будет костыль, но один на весь код, а не в каждом десериализуемом классе

Comment: Спасибо, там не ради двух полей, их намного больше в итоге будет и с обобщением, это как пример просто. Тоже была мысль самому конвертировать это все дело, надеялся обойтись без костылей, жаль.

Answer (score 1):

Воспользуйтесь библиотекой [FSharp.Data](http://fsharp.github.io/FSharp.Data/library/XmlProvider.html). Там есть `XmlProvider`, который сделает вам класс для ваших данных. К сожалению, `TypeProviders` - механизм языка F#, так что вам придётся сделать маленькую F# сборку (~10 строк кода), которую уже можно будет использовать в C# проекте.

Вот весь код, который придётся написать:

```
  open FSharp.Data

  type ExternalService = XmlProvider<""" <eveapi version="2">
                                     <currentTime>2015-11-19 05:21:29</currentTime>
                                     <result>
                                     <serverOpen>True</serverOpen>
                                     <onlinePlayers>14528</onlinePlayers>
                                     </result>
                                     <cachedUntil>2015-11-19 05:23:43</cachedUntil>
                                     </eveapi> """>
```

Далее вы можете подключить проект как зависимость к вашему C# проекту, и использовать класс `ExternalService` как вам захочется. У него на этапе компиляции будут сгенерированы внутренние типы с правильными параметрами.

Comment: Спасибо за совет, но по возможности нужно что бы механизм понимал как десериализовать данные в мою модель, тем более я ни разу не взаимодействовал с F#. Легче написать свой механизм, по-моему.

Comment: @anweledig весь код, которым вы пользуетесь - ваш ;-) И нет, свой механизм написать не легче. Представьте, что данные изменятся - вам вместо того, чтобы поправить сэмпл с этими данными, а затем исправить ошибки использования - придётся изменять кучу классов, что, в принципе, за вас может сделать компилятор. Более того, в "вашем механизме" вы увидите ошибку только в рантайме, но не в момент компиляции.

Comment: TypeProvider'ы - офигенно удобная вещь. Однако, при таком простом создании придётся довольствоваться автоматически определёнными именами свойств - это может не совпасть с моделью данных.

Comment: Что любопытно, `True` в любом регистре распознаётся как булево значение.